# When rows added to a flexbox, box's height increases

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I add more `inbox1` class divs into the div with class `box1`, the height of `box1` increases. You can observe this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75b6oLme/) with red background never disappearing, however many `inbox1`'s are added. What is the reason of this?

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

d1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box2 {
  color: white;
  flex: 12;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inbox1 {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="inbox1">inbox1</div>
      <div class="inbox1">inbox1</div>
      <div class="inbox1">inbox1</div>
      <div class="inbox1">inbox1</div>
      <div class="inbox1">inbox1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit :**

The purpose of this structure is that, `container div` is the content of a website, and `d1` and `d2` divs represent sidebars. However their order is not set in the example because they are needed for the sake of the result.
`Container div` has two parts, **upper**(red background) and **lower**. In my structure this **upper** and **lower** are set as flex boxes in container which is display flex with column direction. **Upper** is also display flex with row direction. However in this set up, as new items are added into the **upper**, the height of the **upper** increases. I dont want it enlarge with added childrens.

Note that, if I remove `d1 and d2 divs` and remove display:flex and related css attributes from `outer div`, and add container in it as a classic relative element, and change **NOTHING** else, this problem magically disappears.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks to oriol, i confirmed this only occurs with chrome.

Comment: Has this structure come about by trial-and-error, or have you built it this way for a reason?  It would be a lot easier to suggest a solution if we knew what you wanted.  Are you just trying to have the left column the same height as the others, but with a flexible box inside, at the top?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox

Comment: @AlexMcMillan There is a reason to build it this way. However it might be bad practice to do it this way. Check edit after this. I am gonna write what i wanna do there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, here is 3 ways to accomplish that

By giving `flex: 0` to your `box1`, you tell it to only be as big as its content, and by adding `max-height: 80px` you say "start scroll" when content gets higher than `80px`

```css
.outer {
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  color: white;
  flex: 0;                     /* changed from 1 to 0  */
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 80px;            /* added                */
}

.box2 {
  color: white;
  flex: 12;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inbox1 {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="d1">
  
  </div>
   <div class="d2">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Set the `flex-basis` to `8%` (box1 has flex 1 and box2 has flex 12, 100 / 12+1 = 7.69) and when content grow beyond that, it starts to scroll.

Note that the `container` needs `height:100%`, so `flex-basis: 8%` have where to get its value.

```css
.outer {
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;                /* added */               
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;                
  flex-basis: 8%;              /* added */
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box2 {
  color: white;
  flex: 12;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inbox1 {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
      <div class="inbox1">
        inbox1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d1">
  </div>
   <div class="d2">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Use an `inner` div with `position: absolute` (since `flex` has some issues to force scroll, this one make it happen)

```css
.outer {
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex: 2;                       /* temp. adjusted to make it slightly bigger        */
  position: relative;            /* added to make position: absolute relate to this  */
}
  .box1 .inner {                 /* added rule to make box1 content scroll           */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
  }

.box2 {
  color: white;
  flex: 12;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inbox1 {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="inbox1">
          inbox1
        </div>
        <div class="inbox1">
          inbox1
        </div>
        <div class="inbox1">
          inbox1
        </div>
        <div class="inbox1">
          inbox1
        </div>
        <div class="inbox1">
          inbox1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d1">
  </div>
   <div class="d2">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solutions. I have tried the one with the basis as flex: 1 8%, weirdly it did not work. But now I made it like you showed, using flex-basis, and it worked. It is weird, because I only have to do this for chrome, which makes me think there might be another problem, as chrome usually is the least problematic browser.

Comment: @OzumSafa Thanks, and why `flex: 1 8%` didn't work is you should do like this `flex: 1 0 8%`, or else the 8% is set to `flex-shrink` which of course becomes invalid.

Comment: @OzumSafa If my answer solved your question, please consider to accept it, and an up vote would be nice :)

Comment: As far as I know flex-shrink is an integer value, and when you do flex: 1 X%, X% is considered as basis

Comment: @OzumSafa You are very right, my wrong. The key is to give each parent of the `box1` a height, and in this case the `container` was missing one, or else a percent value have nothing to compute against.

Comment: I have played a bit more with these in chrome. Chrome is simply refusing to do what flex wants to do. And I still stand very confused. Anything I do works with safari or firefox, chrome just does not wanna keep flex height constant. Right now, even basis does not work. Which should not have done in the first place, as flex-basis is to calculate first width or height, before flex value is considered.

Comment: @OzumSafa Then you need to post the code that doesn't work and we likely will be able to help. Also an image of what you want it to look like might be a good thing.